# Ignoring GET body in python requests

Tags: http, python-requests

I have many URLs where each one is redirected to a new URL.
I want to get the new URLs without getting all of the contents (HTTP GET).
actually, there may be multiple redirects to the final URL, i.e. the requests response history is like `[<Response [301]>, <Response [303]>, <Response [302]>, <Response [302]>]`
Is there a way to do that in python-requests?
At the HTTP level, I wonder if a header or something is available for this.

Answer (score 2):

Your original request will result in `3xx` status and `Location` header will point to new URL. With `python-requests` you have to do requests with `allow_redirects=False`:

```
r = requests.get('http://github.com', allow_redirects=False)
```

See this:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history

Comment: thank you freakish, question updated, my case is something special

Comment: @pajooh If there are multiple redirections and you don't know a priori how many of them there will be then there is nothing you can do except for calling all of them.